# Upgrading version for GWT app using Polymer project

Tags: gwt, polymer, vaadin

I started with developing my project following '[GWT app using Polymer](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/polymer-tutorial/introduction.html)' tutorial with the following dependency versions

1. GWT - 2.7.0
2. vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements - 1.0.2.0.alpha3

I am sofar able to upgrade the 'vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements' to 1.1.3.0-alpha1.
If I try to upgrade it further, to say 1.7.0.0,

There are build errors...

```
[INFO]                [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/polymer/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements/1.7.0.0/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements-1.7.0.0.jar!/com/vaadin/polymer/iron/event/IronChangeEvent.java'
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 11: The import jsinterop cannot be resolved
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 13: The import jsinterop cannot be resolved
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 21: JsOverlay cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 18: JsType cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/polymer/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements/1.7.0.0/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements-1.7.0.0.jar!/com/vaadin/polymer/iron/event/IronOverlayOpenedEvent.java'
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 11: The import jsinterop cannot be resolved
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 13: The import jsinterop cannot be resolved
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 21: JsOverlay cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 18: JsType cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/polymer/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements/1.7.0.0/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements-1.7.0.0.jar!/com/vaadin/polymer/iron/event/IronOverlayCanceledEvent.java'
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 12: The import jsinterop cannot be resolved
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 13: The import jsinterop cannot be resolved
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 21: JsOverlay cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 27: JsType cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 18: JsType cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 11: The import jsinterop cannot be resolved
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 33: JsProperty cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 24: JsProperty cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/polymer/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements/1.7.0.0/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements-1.7.0.0.jar!/com/vaadin/polymer/iron/event/IronOverlayClosedEvent.java'
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 12: The import jsinterop cannot be resolved
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 13: The import jsinterop cannot be resolved
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 21: JsOverlay cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 27: JsType cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 18: JsType cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 11: The import jsinterop cannot be resolved
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 33: JsProperty cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 24: JsProperty cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/polymer/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements/1.7.0.0/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements-1.7.0.0.jar!/com/vaadin/polymer/paper/event/ContentScrollEvent.java'
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 11: The import jsinterop cannot be resolved
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 13: The import jsinterop cannot be resolved
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 21: JsOverlay cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 18: JsType cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/polymer/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements/1.7.0.0/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements-1.7.0.0.jar!/com/vaadin/polymer/iron/event/IronItemsChangedEvent.java'
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 11: The import jsinterop cannot be resolved
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 13: The import jsinterop cannot be resolved
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 21: JsOverlay cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 18: JsType cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/polymer/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements/1.7.0.0/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements-1.7.0.0.jar!/com/vaadin/polymer/iron/event/IronActivateEvent.java'
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 12: The import jsinterop cannot be resolved
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 38: JsProperty cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 13: The import jsinterop cannot be resolved
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 21: JsOverlay cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 27: JsType cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 18: JsType cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 11: The import jsinterop cannot be resolved
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 33: JsProperty cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 24: JsProperty cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]    [ERROR] Errors in 'com/l3/client/Injector.java'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 19: Failed to resolve 'com.l3.client.Injector' via deferred binding
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 23.554 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-11T14:05:58+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/227M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:compile (default) on project L3mart: Command [[
[ERROR] /bin/sh -c '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java' '-Xmx512m' '-classpath' '/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/git/L3Mart/target/classes:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/git/L3Mart/src/main/java:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.7.0/gwt-user-2.7.0.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.7.0/gwt-dev-2.7.0.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.3/asm-5.0.3.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/5.0.3/asm-util-5.0.3.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/5.0.3/asm-tree-5.0.3.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/5.0.3/asm-commons-5.0.3.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-codeserver/2.7.0/gwt-codeserver-2.7.0.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/polymer/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements/1.7.0.0/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements-1.7.0.0.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk/1.9.44/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.44.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/objectify/objectify/5.1.13/objectify-5.1.13.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/19.0/guava-19.0.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava-gwt/19.0/guava-gwt-19.0.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.0.2/error_prone_annotations-2.0.2.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/0.1/j2objc-annotations-0.1.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/inject/gin/2.1.2/gin-2.1.2.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/4.1.0/guice-4.1.0.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/extensions/guice-servlet/4.1.0/guice-servlet-4.1.0.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/extensions/guice-assistedinject/4.1.0/guice-assistedinject-4.1.0.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/l3/gwt/plupload/gwt-plupload/1.1/gwt-plupload-1.1.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.1/httpclient-4.5.1.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.3/httpcore-4.4.3.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.7.0/gwt-user-2.7.0.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.7.0/gwt-dev-2.7.0.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.3/asm-5.0.3.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/5.0.3/asm-util-5.0.3.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/5.0.3/asm-tree-5.0.3.jar:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/5.0.3/asm-commons-5.0.3.jar' 'com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler' '-logLevel' 'INFO' '-style' 'OBF' '-war' '/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/git/L3Mart/target/L3mart-1.0-SNAPSHOT' '-localWorkers' '4' '-compileReport' '-XfragmentCount' '-1' '-sourceLevel' '1.7' '-XjsInteropMode' 'JS' '-extra' '/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/git/L3Mart/target/extra' '-gen' '/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/git/L3Mart/target/.generated' 'com.l3.L3Mart' 'com.l3.Mart' 'com.l3.User'
[ERROR] ]] failed with status 1
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

When I upgrade the GWT version to 2.8.0 
Now the build errors are

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building com.l3.l3mart 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ L3mart ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/aadhaarmehrotra/git/L3Mart/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ L3mart ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ L3mart ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/aadhaarmehrotra/git/L3Mart/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ L3mart ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ L3mart ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.8.0:compile (default) @ L3mart ---
[ERROR] Source level must be one of [auto, 1.8].
[ERROR] Google Web Toolkit 2.8.0
[ERROR] Compiler [-logLevel (ERROR|WARN|INFO|TRACE|DEBUG|SPAM|ALL)] [-workDir dir] [-X[no]closureFormattedOutput] [-[no]compileReport] [-X[no]checkCasts] [-X[no]classMetadata] [-[no]draftCompile] [-[no]checkAssertions] [-XfragmentCount numFragments] [-XfragmentMerge numFragments] [-gen dir] [-[no]generateJsInteropExports] [-XmethodNameDisplayMode (NONE|ONLY_METHOD_NAME|ABBREVIATED|FULL)] [-Xnamespace (NONE|PACKAGE)] [-optimize level] [-[no]saveSource] [-setProperty name=value,value...] [-style (DETAILED|OBFUSCATED|PRETTY)] [-[no]failOnError] [-[no]validateOnly] [-sourceLevel [auto, 1.8]] [-localWorkers count] [-[no]incremental] [-war dir] [-deploy dir] [-extra dir] [-saveSourceOutput dir] module[s] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] where 
[ERROR]   -logLevel                      The level of logging detail: ERROR, WARN, INFO, TRACE, DEBUG, SPAM or ALL (defaults to INFO)
[ERROR]   -workDir                       The compiler's working directory for internal use (must be writeable; defaults to a system temp dir)
[ERROR]   -X[no]closureFormattedOutput   EXPERIMENTAL: Enables Javascript output suitable for post-compilation by Closure Compiler (defaults to OFF)
[ERROR]   -[no]compileReport             Compile a report that tells the "Story of Your Compile". (defaults to ON)
[ERROR]   -X[no]checkCasts               EXPERIMENTAL: DEPRECATED: use jre.checks.checkLevel instead. (defaults to OFF)
[ERROR]   -X[no]classMetadata            EXPERIMENTAL: Include metadata for some java.lang.Class methods (e.g. getName()). (defaults to ON)
[ERROR]   -[no]draftCompile              Compile quickly with minimal optimizations. (defaults to OFF)
[ERROR]   -[no]checkAssertions           Include assert statements in compiled output. (defaults to OFF)
[ERROR]   -XfragmentCount                EXPERIMENTAL: Limits of number of fragments using a code splitter that merges split points.
[ERROR]   -XfragmentMerge                DEPRECATED (use -XfragmentCount instead): Enables Fragment merging code splitter.
[ERROR]   -gen                           Debugging: causes normally-transient generated types to be saved in the specified directory
[ERROR]   -[no]generateJsInteropExports  Generate exports for JsInterop purposes (defaults to OFF)
[ERROR]   -XmethodNameDisplayMode        EXPERIMENTAL: Specifies method display name mode for chrome devtools: NONE, ONLY_METHOD_NAME, ABBREVIATED or FULL (defaults to NONE)
[ERROR]   -Xnamespace                    Puts most JavaScript globals into namespaces. Default: PACKAGE for -draftCompile, otherwise NONE
[ERROR]   -optimize                      Sets the optimization level used by the compiler.  0=none 9=maximum.
[ERROR]   -[no]saveSource                Enables saving source code needed by debuggers. Also see -debugDir. (defaults to OFF)
[ERROR]   -setProperty                   Set the values of a property in the form of propertyName=value1[,value2...].
[ERROR]   -style                         Script output style: DETAILED, OBFUSCATED or PRETTY (defaults to OBFUSCATED)
[ERROR]   -[no]failOnError               Fail compilation if any input file contains an error. (defaults to OFF)
[ERROR]   -[no]validateOnly              Validate all source code, but do not compile. (defaults to OFF)
[ERROR]   -sourceLevel                   Specifies Java source level (defaults to 1.8)
[ERROR]   -localWorkers                  The number of local workers to use when compiling permutations
[ERROR]   -[no]incremental               Compiles faster by reusing data from the previous compile. (defaults to OFF)
[ERROR]   -war                           The directory into which deployable output files will be written (defaults to 'war')
[ERROR]   -deploy                        The directory into which deployable but not servable output files will be written (defaults to 'WEB-INF/deploy' under the -war directory/jar, and may be the same as the -extra directory/jar)
[ERROR]   -extra                         The directory into which extra files, not intended for deployment, will be written
[ERROR]   -saveSourceOutput              Overrides where source files useful to debuggers will be written. Default: saved with extras.
[ERROR] and 
[ERROR]   module[s]                      Specifies the name(s) of the module(s) to compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.861 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-11T14:12:52+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/227M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.8.0:compile (default) on project L3mart: Command [[
[ERROR] /bin/sh -c '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java' '-Xmx512m' 'com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler' '-logLevel' 'INFO' '-war' '/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/git/L3Mart/target/L3mart-1.0-SNAPSHOT' '-localWorkers' '4' '-compileReport' '-XfragmentCount' '-1' '-sourceLevel' '1.7' '-extra' '/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/git/L3Mart/target/extra' '-gen' '/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/git/L3Mart/target/.generated' 'com.l3.L3Mart' 'com.l3.Mart' 'com.l3.User'
[ERROR] ]] failed with status 1
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

This requires a source level to be 1.8.
So I added '1.8' to the 'gwt-maven-plugin'.

Now the build errors are...

```
[INFO]    Resolving java.util.function.IntToLongFunction
[INFO]       Found type 'java.util.function.IntToLongFunction'
[INFO]          [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
[INFO]    Resolving java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator
[INFO]       Found type 'java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator'
[INFO]          [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
[INFO]    Resolving java.util.function.LongBinaryOperator
[INFO]       Found type 'java.util.function.LongBinaryOperator'
[INFO]          [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
[INFO]    Resolving java.util.function.LongPredicate
[INFO]       Found type 'java.util.function.LongPredicate'
[INFO]          [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
[INFO]    Resolving java.util.function.LongSupplier
[INFO]       Found type 'java.util.function.LongSupplier'
[INFO]          [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
[INFO]    Resolving java.util.function.LongToDoubleFunction
[INFO]       Found type 'java.util.function.LongToDoubleFunction'
[INFO]          [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
[INFO]    Resolving java.util.function.LongToIntFunction
[INFO]       Found type 'java.util.function.LongToIntFunction'
[INFO]          [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
[INFO]    Resolving java.util.function.LongUnaryOperator
[INFO]       Found type 'java.util.function.LongUnaryOperator'
[INFO]          [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
[INFO]    Resolving java.util.function.ToDoubleBiFunction
[INFO]       Found type 'java.util.function.ToDoubleBiFunction'
[INFO]          [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
[INFO]    Resolving java.util.function.ToIntBiFunction
[INFO]       Found type 'java.util.function.ToIntBiFunction'
[INFO]          [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
[INFO]    Resolving java.util.function.ToLongBiFunction
[INFO]       Found type 'java.util.function.ToLongBiFunction'
[INFO]          [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type java.lang.FunctionalInterface
[INFO]    Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.l3.client.Injector'
[INFO]       Rebinding com.l3.client.Injector
[INFO]          Checking rule <generate-with class='com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.GinjectorGenerator'/>
[INFO]             Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.l3.client.Injector'
[INFO]                [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/git/L3Mart/src/main/java/com/l3/client/Injector.java'
[INFO]                   [ERROR] com.l3.client.user.UserController cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/git/L3Mart/src/main/java/com/l3/client/mart/MartController.java'
[INFO]                   [ERROR] com.l3.client.mart.view.MartBodyWidget cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/git/L3Mart/src/main/java/com/l3/client/user/UserController.java'
[INFO]                   [ERROR] com.l3.client.user.view.BodyWidget cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/git/L3Mart/src/main/java/com/l3/client/mart/view/MartBodyWidget.java'
[INFO]                   [ERROR] com.l3.client.mart.view.MartContentWidget cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/git/L3Mart/src/main/java/com/l3/client/user/view/BodyWidget.java'
[INFO]                   [ERROR] com.l3.client.user.view.product.UpdateProductDialog cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/git/L3Mart/src/main/java/com/l3/client/mart/view/MartContentWidget.java'
[INFO]                   [ERROR] com.l3.client.mart.view.cart.CartWidget cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/git/L3Mart/src/main/java/com/l3/client/user/view/product/UpdateProductDialog.java'
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 152: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to String
[INFO]                [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/git/L3Mart/src/main/java/com/l3/client/mart/view/cart/CartWidget.java'
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 41: PaperBadgeElement cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 26: PaperBadgeElement cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Line 11: The import com.vaadin.polymer.paper.element cannot be resolved
[INFO]    [ERROR] Errors in 'com/l3/client/Injector.java'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 19: Failed to resolve 'com.l3.client.Injector' via deferred binding
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 56.345 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-11T14:18:48+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/227M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.8.0:compile (default) on project L3mart: Command [[
[ERROR] /bin/sh -c '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java' '-Xmx512m' 'com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler' '-logLevel' 'INFO' '-war' '/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/git/L3Mart/target/L3mart-1.0-SNAPSHOT' '-localWorkers' '4' '-compileReport' '-XfragmentCount' '-1' '-sourceLevel' '1.8' '-extra' '/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/git/L3Mart/target/extra' '-gen' '/Users/aadhaarmehrotra/git/L3Mart/target/.generated' 'com.l3.L3Mart' 'com.l3.Mart' 'com.l3.User'
[ERROR] ]] failed with status 1
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

The polymer alpha version has bugs and I am not able to upgrade it to a stable version, please suggest the way out. Many Thanks.

I am also using the following versions if they may be causing an incompatibility

1. com.google.guava - 19.0
2. com.google.gwt.inject GIN - 2.1.2
3. com.google.inject GUICE - 4.1.0
4. appengine-api-1.0-sdk - 1.9.44

Comment: You need Guava 20, and you might need a workaround for GIN (see GWT release notes)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. With Guava 20.0, it is building fine now.